# Unable to add cxf bundle package in Eclipse

Tags: cxf

I'm trying to learn apache cxf and axis2.
I created a java project in Eclipse Helios and also added Maven Integration for Eclipse. After that, I enabled Dependency Management on that project. But when I select add Dependency and enter cxf in the search box, it doesn't return any result.
According to the book I'm using (Developing Web Services with Apache CXF & Axis2), it should return org.apache.cxf bundle package.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Enter `cxf-bundle` instead of `cxf`. I don't know why, but entering `cxf` alone does not return any results. `cxf-bundle` does, though.